# Dazed and confused about configuring Apache with SSL support

Tags: apache, configuration, ssl, openssl, mod-ssl

I've spent a few hours trying to configure my Apache server to use SSL with no public IP, just localhost. I've created the certificate OK, I think (it has been like a crash course on black magic for me), and when I try tro access https://localhost, the browser says "Connected to localhost..." on the status line but just keeps loading forever. Here's a snippet from `error_log`:

```
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
```

everything seems to be OK there, but, meanwhile, at `ssl_engine_log`...

```
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Initializing OpenSSL library
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] mod_ssl/2.0.61 compiled against Server: Apache/2.0.61, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.7i
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Initializing OpenSSL library
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 136 bytes of entropy[Fri Mar 27 22:03:39 2009] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [info] mod_ssl/2.0.61 compiled against Server: Apache/2.0.61, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.7i
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [notice] Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.61 OpenSSL/0.9.7l DAV/2 PHP/5.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [info] Server built: Jan 17 2008 17:33:42
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [emerg] (13)Permission denied: apr_proc_mutex_lock failed. Attempting to shutdown process gracefully.
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:40 2009] [emerg] (13)Permission denied: apr_proc_mutex_lock failed. Attempting to shutdown process gracefully.
```

...many more like these last two lines, until I finally stop the server...

```
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:43 2009] [info] removed PID file /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid (pid=8786)
[Fri Mar 27 22:03:43 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

some googling about this `permission denied` and the `apr_proc_mutex_lock` failing hasn't yielded anything useful. Only some results relating to MPM and perchild option, but as they were old (years 2002 and 2003) and I don't really can draw any conclusions after reading them, I'm asking you if there is a way to overcome this problem. Well, first: what is actually the problem? Is there any kind of incompatibility between modules? Do I have to recompile something (please, Lord, not again, no)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close as this is not about programming and would probably fit better in an Apache forum.

Comment: The question is also weak: For example, the title is trying to be cute rather than informative.

Comment: Naw.  There isn't a good place to ask these kinds of questions and quite frankly, if this doesn't fall into the theme of the site, the theme needs to be broadened to include it.

That said, it is hard to answer without knowing the configuration and operating system.

Answer (score 4):

Just be thankful you aren't using apache 1.3--it was way harder to get SSL running on that!

mod_ssl needs write permission on a couple files for it to work.  Take a look at [this setting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslmutex) and make sure apache has write access to the directory that file is in.  For example, if says (for example):

`SSLMutex file:/var/run/apache/ssl.mutex`

You need to verify apache can write to `/var/run/apache`.

Almost all of these kinds of errors are usually some kind of permission error on the filesystem.

Comment: Well, thanks so much, man. My problem wasn't really in the directory permissions, but your link has been most helpful! I have spent some more time reading directive descriptions and, after adding AcceptMutex, I am able to connect. I'm not trying to sound cute, just to say that appreciate your help.